# problem in importing xgboost module (Error message(s): ['[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application'])

Tags: python, openmp, python-import, importerror, xgboost

I have installed xgboost using xgboost-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl the error says to install either of the two vcomp140.dll or libgomp-1.dll I tried with both but shows no result I am not using conda I am using jupyter notebook.

```
import xgboost

XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e444c8490328> in <module>
----> 1 from xgboost import XGBRegressor
      2 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      3 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

c:\users\aarja\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\xgboost\__init__.py in <module>
      9 import warnings
     10 
---> 11 from .core import DMatrix, DeviceQuantileDMatrix, Booster
     12 from .training import train, cv
     13 from . import rabit  # noqa

c:\users\aarja\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in <module>
    173 
    174 # load the XGBoost library globally
--> 175 _LIB = _load_lib()
    176 
    177 

c:\users\aarja\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in _load_lib()
    164             '`brew install libomp` to install OpenMP runtime.\n' +
    165             '  * You are running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS\n' +
--> 166             'Error message(s): {}\n'.format(os_error_list))
    167     lib.XGBGetLastError.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
    168     lib.callback = _get_log_callback_func()

XGBoostError: XGBoost Library (xgboost.dll) could not be loaded.
Likely causes:
  * OpenMP runtime is not installed (vcomp140.dll or libgomp-1.dll for Windows, libomp.dylib for Mac OSX, libgomp.so for Linux and other UNIX-like OSes). Mac OSX users: Run `brew install libomp` to install OpenMP runtime.
  * You are running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS
Error message(s): ['[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application']
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but it took me a while to fix. I downloaded [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=48145) but it Did not work for me and i still had the same issue. it turns out that the XGBOOST that I had downloaded, needed a newer version of Visual C++ Redistributable so here is what I did:

1. Uninstall XGBOOST using `pip uninstall xgboost`
2. Download [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable latest supported downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170)
3. Restart your Computer
4. Install XGBOOST using `pip install xgboost`

Answer (score 0):

The issue very likely lies in [missing Visual Studio C++ Redistributable binaries](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/missing-vcomp140dll/afca0b6b-3ced-4e82-8ce8-8734a440d516).

You can install them from the [official link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=48145). They are dependency of many of the C++ libraries compiled on Windows that expose Python API (or python modules that are in fact interfacing into C++ libraries).

In your case, assuming the installation went well, OpenMP is installed but its dependency is missing. If you face a similar issue after installing VC Redist package then you should check installation of OpenMP DLLs. Or install a precompiled version using `pip install xgboost` on 64b Windows.